# 20 dB/Decade - Justification

Tags: control-system, stability, bode-plot, phase-margin

I've read that it is recommended to have 20 dB/Decade slope on the L(jw) magnitude plot of the Bode Diagram at gain crossover.  This seems to imply a slope of -1 in dimensionless terms.

However, what is the justification for this?  The reasoning for this always seems to be glossed over.

Also, in Astrom's text he claims the gain slope must be greater than -2 for stability.  I have a tuned up system that as a gain slope of -2.3 and is still stable.  Granted, it's barely stable, but there is phase margin left.

What is the justification for that statement of -2 for stability?  Is -2 a rough number?

Thanks for any feedback and help!

Comment: Does "greater" in the text mean "steeper" or "closer to zero"? (Perhaps you could quote the text verbatim, or better, scan an excerpt)

Comment: Unfortunately, that is basically verbatim from the text.  They leave much to be desired  in the way of details at times.  I interpreted it as -1.8 > -2 and -2.3 < -2, as a couple examples.  So, a steeper drop off on the magnitude plot would be less than -2, if I am correct in my interpretation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a system with a single signal path through it, (a system with no parallel branches, so no lattice filters for instance), also known as minimum phase, a gain slope of -1 or 20dB/decade implies a phase shift of 90 degrees, see the [Hilbert Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_transform).

This means that a closed loop system will have plenty of phase margin if the gain slope crosses 0dB at 20dB/decade. It's common to use rather more than that, up to 30dB total being not unusual in amplifiers and phase locked loops, 45 degrees phase margin will give a little overshoot, but it's fairly tame.

It's worth remembering that in PLLs, the fact that the VCO is controlled in frequency but measured in phase means that even with no loop filter, you have a 90 degree shift and a -20dB/decade gain slope. Adding a single lowpass filtering element will at some frequencies give you another 90 degrees, which with latency and strays become more than 90 degrees. No wonder that the first PLL put together by a noob is almost certain to be unstable (mine included!) and people often surround them with an aura of magic. This has led to my PLL design method which is (a) with no loop filter, set the loop bandwidth via the gain (b) add integrator element(s) as required, breaking away below the loop bandwidth (c) add lowpass elements as required above the loop bandwidth such that (d) the sum of all phase shifts from the loop filter at the loop bandwidth is 45 degrees or less.

A good reason for aiming well below -30dB slope with the elements you can control is that you'll always have some extra phase shift for free that you didn't intend, from stray capacitance, non-zero output impedance, finite gain.bandwidth products etc.

Once you get to -2, you have 180 degrees phase shift, and the system will become unstable. Less extreme than -2, and you have stability.

If you have a system with a -2.3 gain slope and some phase margin left for stability, then you have a non-minimum phase system, or a measurement or description error.

Comment: Thanks Neil.  Is there any math that shows the relationship between the -2 slope and the 180 degrees phase shift?  Perhaps the Bode Gain/Phase equation is needed?

I guess it comes from my physics background, but I always feel the need to see the mathematical justification to get the best intuitive feel for what's going on.

Comment: Just took a look and the Bode Gain/Phase relations do give exactly what you stated!  However, it does say these relationships are valid for minimum phase systems only.  I think this is where my confusion was coming in.  I am dealing with a non-minimum phase system with one pole in the RHP.

Comment: Neil, why do you qualify with "In a pure cascaded system"? Cascading with an all-pass ruins the 90deg/20dB relationship. Did you perhaps mean "minimum phase"?

Comment: @P2000 Yes, minimum phase, which is guarranteed by having a single path through the filter. A good way to get other than minimum phase is to have two or more parallel paths through the filter, though the criterion was always taught to me as a single cascade, emphasizing for instance it was still valid when you cascaded min phase filter stages.

Comment: Thanks @Neil_UK I hadn't thought of it that way.

Answer (score 1):

> *However, what is the justification for this?*

If the rate at which gain is falling is 20 dB/decade then it's highly likely that the circuit/system is 1st order and cannot produce a phase angle change of more than 90° from lowest frequency to highest frequency. This would be inherently stable when feedback is applied.

> *in Astrom's text he claims the gain slope must be greater than -2 for
> stability.*

That sounds like a 2nd order system and the maximum phase angle produced could be 180° and be borderline stable with negative feedback. However `greater than -2` could mean -1.9 or -1.8 or etc. and this would then become more stable when feedback is used.